# Where do I put my ui.router templates in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am working on a basic Rails/Angular app and am using ui.router to control the views. However when I try to use `templateUrl` I get a `localhost/app/assets/templates/partial-home.html` error. Where should I be putting these partials to make available to rails?

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        template: "this is a test of the state provider",
        //templateUrl: 'app/assets/templates/partial-home.html',
        controller: 'testCtrl'
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

i'm using [angular-rails-template](https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates), which also caches the HTML templates into Angular's `$templateCache` to save AJAX calls or manually injecting the templates.

so, for templates in: `assets/javascripts/templates`
(i've added instructions for your setup, haven't tested it though)

- `gem 'angular-rails-templates'` and `bundle`
- require the templates js in the manifest (probably `application.js`)

  ```
  //= require angularjs
  //= require angular-rails-templates
  //= require_tree ./templates
  ```

  (in your setup, the include should be: `//= require_tree ../templates` (not tested), and you should change the [ignore_prefix settings](https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates#configuration-option-ignore_prefix))
- inject dependancies: `angular.module('myApplication', ['templates']);`
- use your template in your ui-router js:

  ```
  $stateProvider.state('home', {

    url: '/',

    // Template on: app/assets/javascripts/templates/partial-home.html

    templateUrl: 'partial-home.html', //should work now :)

    controller: 'testCtrl' 

    }); 

  });
  ```

that's it.
let me know how it goes

Comment: You also have to have sprockets version >= 2.12